# Paypal wallet creation using java for a mobile app

Tags: java, paypal

I need to integrate paypal wallet for a e-commerce application. is there any way to create using java.  Can you share any api links and integration steps. thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You'll have to be more specific about what you mean by "paypal wallet" -- but if you mean a [PayPal Checkout](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/checkout/) with a Java backend, the server-side SDK is here: https://github.com/paypal/Checkout-Java-SDK

There's some documentation here: https://developer.paypal.com/docs/checkout/reference/server-integration/set-up-transaction/ -- in particular you'll need routes on your server to 'Set Up Transaction' and 'Capture Transaction'.

Once you have those two routes to create and capture an order, they can be paired with the web front-end: https://developer.paypal.com/demo/checkout/#/pattern/server